# Why does a process in a computer sometime consume all the CPU?

Tags: multithreading, memory-management, process, operating-system

I have read that processes in a computer are scheduled on a CPU based on time slices. If that is the case, a thread should never consume 100% CPU for extended periods of time and the system should never hang. What is wrong in this line of reasoning?

Comment: Processes are not scheduled, threads are.  And if a thread has a decent computational job to do then it will burn core.  Even if that means that it will consume 100% the machine still doesn't hang, the OS gives everybody a shot at it.  Since threads are scheduled by priority.  A thread that's been starved for a while automatically gets its priority boosted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a thread that is always executable, especially on a system with multiple processors, it is easy to get 100% CPU. If a processor has nothing to do, it might as well give time to a thread that is ready.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't if there were no defects in software/hardware management and running environment. A computer usually hangs when there is any defect in one or more processes while multitasking. These defects could be

- virtual memory is in constant paging for a process (thrashing)
- insufficient RAM for the multitasking
- non pre-emptive multitasking
- hardware performance is not as expected
- faulty resource management

When one or more of the above happens, a thread in execution continues to hold on resources for extended periods, sometimes resulting a hang.